# How to retrieve My Places maps data from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is it still possible using JavaScript to get My Places data out of Maps? With the move to Fusion Tables and deprecation of the Maps Data API, I can't seem to find information on how to get this data...if it's even available in FT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maps Data API was the only programmatic endpoint to accessing this dataset.  However you can still export the data by selecting a map, and then clicking the KML link.

A variety of tools are available for visualizing, importing, and converting KML data in case you want to import it elsewhere.

Comment: I don't want to import it, just use it. This is what I thought; thanks.